# Google Custom Search not showing any results maybe because of META tags

Tags: php, html, meta-tags, meta, google-custom-search

I have a website http://www.ssdpsjal.tk and I have implemented Google Custom Search in it according to all the steps given in instructions.

I had Indexed my site about 3 months ago but the custom search is still showing no result after so many days. I have even tried to add `sitemap.xml` but no luck.

Another problem is when I simply search ssdpsjal.tk on Google, it displays result (somewhat) which are only 3 but these are not even showing in GCSE.

You can visit the website and try the custom search.

What can I do about it? (Any Alternatives or fixes are required!)

My code is

```
<div class="remove-style">
   <script>
        (function() {
            var cx = 'MY_WEBSITE_KEY';
            var gcse = document.createElement('script');
            gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
            gcse.async = true;
            gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
        })();
    </script>
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
</div>
```

Help Appreciated!

**EDIT**

After some searches, I have found that it only points to the the home page on any search or external website links, are my Meta Tags Correct?

I have used same meta tags and values for each and every page on the website. Do I need to change them? What are the required Tags.

If my tags are correct, then what is the Error.

Please Help

Comment: Meta Tags only come into play (especially for content and keywords) if everything else has been looked at and the search engine has 2 pages ranked the same. You should change them, as it's a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Your custom search engine seems to be working on my end. I did a few searches and everything looks fine. Just make sure to click on the blue button and you'll see the results following paid AdWords links.

As for your search results in google. You need to work on your SEO (search engine optimization). You can either contact a firm to do the work for you or do some yourself but there is tons of work. Just be sure to use "white hat" techniques like making sure your site is W3C compliant, making sure your website works in all supported browsers (yes that means mobile as well), Even page speed loads affect your SERP (search engine results page). There are tons of websites and forums that teach you about SEO like http://www.moz.com and http://www.searchengineland.com. Even stackover has a webmaster section dedicated for people just like you https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Can I know what did you search for and in which browser?

Comment: I used Chrome, Firefox and Safari.